# Give out value of a function variable

Tags: python

I have a code for a VoiceActivityDetector and want to give out the value speech_ratio which is in a function

I tried to set up a new function to print out the value

```
 def __init__(self, wave_input_filename):
        self._read_wav(wave_input_filename)._convert_to_mono()
        self.sample_window = 0.02 #20 ms
        self.sample_overlap = 0.01 #10ms
        self.speech_window = 0.5 #half a second
        self.speech_energy_threshold = 0.6 #60% of energy in voice band
        self.speech_start_band = 300
        self.speech_end_band = 3000
        #self.speech_ratio = 0



def detect_speech(self):
        """ Detects speech regions based on ratio between speech band energy
        and total energy.
        Output is array of window numbers and speech flags (1 - speech, 0 - nonspeech).
        """
        detected_windows = np.array([])
        sample_window = int(self.rate * self.sample_window)
        sample_overlap = int(self.rate * self.sample_overlap)
        data = self.data
        sample_start = 0
        start_band = self.speech_start_band
        end_band = self.speech_end_band
        while (sample_start < (len(data) - sample_window)):
            sample_end = sample_start + sample_window
            if sample_end>=len(data): sample_end = len(data)-1
            data_window = data[sample_start:sample_end]
            energy_freq = self._calculate_normalized_energy(data_window)
            sum_voice_energy = self._sum_energy_in_band(energy_freq, start_band, end_band)
            sum_full_energy = sum(energy_freq.values())
            speech_ratio = sum_voice_energy/sum_full_energy
            #self.speech_ratio2 = speech_ratio
            # Hipothesis is that when there is a speech sequence we have ratio of energies more than Threshold
            speech_ratio = speech_ratio>self.speech_energy_threshold

            detected_windows = np.append(detected_windows,[sample_start, speech_ratio])
            sample_start += sample_overlap
        detected_windows = detected_windows.reshape(int(len(detected_windows)/2),2)
        detected_windows[:,1] = self._smooth_speech_detection(detected_windows)
        return detected_windows

def printing(self):
            print(self.speech_ratio)
            return self.speech_ratio
```

When I set speech_ratio as a variable in the **init** it does not change the variable later on in the detect_speech function.
If I do not initialize speech_ratio in the **init** function it wont be a attribute of my object at all.

Comment: A smaller sample code is usually easier to fix such issues

Answer (score 1):

You use `self.speech_ratio` to try and print the value; you should use the same expression to assign to it.